# how to show only hh:mm in DataTimePicker?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i have DataTimePicker control in my form.

i want to show only hh:mm

how i can do it ?

thank's in advance

Comment: What date timer picker control are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Format` property to `Custom`.

Set the `CustomFormat` property to `HH:mm` for 24-hour time or `hh:mm` for 12-hour time.

See [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use the customformat Property....
See the custom formats in msdn  DateTime.ToString() overloads

Answer (score -1):

```
$('selector').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd hh:nn'});
```

as shown in the [datepicker documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#options). (There are also ways to pre-define default settings, so you don't have to do that every time. See the documentation for details.)

Comment: I think he is talking about the WinForms DateTimePicker, nothing to do with jQuery here.